# Escapaing FINDSTR Characters

Tags: windows, cmd, escaping, findstr

I have been unsucessful in escapaing a combination of letters within my FINDSTR search query. My query contains a quote mark (") and a chvron (>).

My search query = **findstr /N /C:"font-size:10px">" inputfile.txt > outpputfile.txt**

I have serached the web and this site for solutions. I have managed to successfully escape the quote mark by placing my quote within two other quotes i.e. "font-size:10px""""

Can I get some help in determineing how I can escape the **BOTH** the quote and chevron to make my query successful.

PS - Ultimately, I am trying to develop a search to find all matches for the string **font-size:10px">AAAA.** where the letters *AAAA* represent any number between 1-9999 followed by a period (.) - if you can provide some solution/support with that I would be even more greatful (if that is possible :)

Answer (score 2):

The escape character of the `findstr` command is the backslash, so `"` must be expressed by `\"`. However, you need to regard, that the Command Interpreter `cmd.exe` also recognises quotation marks, and that it uses another character for escaping, namely the caret symbol, leading to this:

```cmd
findstr /N /R /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[0-9][0-9]*\.^" "inputfile.txt" > "outputfile.txt"
```

In this command line, the portion `font-size:10px\` appears quoted to `cmd.exe`. The subsequent characters appears unquoted, that is why the `>` character must be escaped like `^>`. The `.` is a special character for `findstr`, so we must escape it like `\.`. The closing quotation mark for the search expression must be escaped like `^"` in order to hide it from `cmd.exe`, because there is an unbalanced number of quotation marks, which would otherwise affect the remaining command line.

Note, that `[0-9]` may also match characters like `¹`, `²`, `³`, depending on the current code page. To avoid that, use the following expression instead:

```cmd
findstr /N /R /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[0123456789][0123456789]*\.^" "inputfile.txt" > "outputfile.txt"
```

As you may have noticed, I have quoted all file names. this is not necessary in this particular situation, but it is best practice to avoid troubles with file paths/names containing white-spaces or other special characters.

Comment: supereb! However, I see that the search results are only for matches where the search string contains numbers equal or greater than 1001. If the numbers are between 1-1000 the matches are not being found. Any thoughts?

Comment: See my edit – the numeric part may now be arbitrarily long (one or more digits). Just let me know if that is acceptable or if you do not want to accept numbers with more than four digits…

Comment: My requirement was for four digits; so that's fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the question specifically stated:

> where the letters AAAA represent any number between 1-9999

The more complete code would be:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[23456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789][0123456789][012345678]\." "inputfile.txt" 1>"outputfile.txt"
```

As you can see, I've used the `/C` option in four different combinations; to match for numbers `2` to `9`, numbers `10` to `99`, numbers `100` to `999`, and numbers `1000` to `9998`; thus catering for all possible whole numbers 'between' those requested.

---

If you really meant `1` to `9999` inclusive, then a quick modification is all you need:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\." /C:"font-size:10px\"^>[123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]\." "inputfile.txt" 1>"outputfile.txt"
```